# Retain text in field after failed login attempt

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a login form and when I attempt to login and fail I am sent back to the login form and it is blank. I want to retain the username/email address field on a failed attempt so that I just need to type in the password again. Any suggestions on what I need to do?

HTML:

```
            <?php if ($_GET['msg'] == 'failed') : ?>
        <p style="color:red; font-weight: bold">Incorrect email or password. Try again!</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <form action="index.php?cmd=login" method="post" id="form">
            <div class="signup-form">
                <p>
                    <label>Email</label>
                     <input type="text" name="email" value="" class="textbox required email" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="textbox required"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label></label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" value="1" class="" checked="checked" /> Remember Me?
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a style="margin: 10px 0 0 0; color:#000;" class="button" href="javascript://" onclick="$('#form').submit()">Continue</a> <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" class="loading" style="display: none;" />
```

And:

```
 if ($_POST) {
$login = $_USER->do_log_in(input($_POST['email']), md5($_POST['password']), $_POST['rememberme']);
if ($login == true) {
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $_USER->get_user_id();
    header('location: index.php');
}else
    header('location: index.php?cmd=login&msg=failed');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) { echo $_POST['email']; } ?>" class="textbox required email" />
```

you just have to use `isset` method and check weather it is set or not. If yes dispaly its text in `value`.

Comment: I pass my POST data to another page and then the header redirect sends it back to the form page, the header redirect clears out the POST data. Is it safe to do this? `header('location: index.php?cmd=login&msg=failed&email='.$_POST['email']);`

Comment: do header redirection when the login is done else don't redirect them.